# LAMP with Hudson: How to run SQL Statement every hour

Tags: sql, mysql, hudson, lamp

I'm using CentOS 5.5, Apache, MySQL and PHP. I also installed Hudson. Now I would like to run an SQL Statement every hour. What is the easiest way? Should I use Cron or Hudson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cron` is pluggable as long your box is with crond enable,
use less resource unlike java-based hudson,

> As a Java-based web application, Hudson is heavyweight. A low-memory or embedded system is better-off with cron. Even Hudson’s remote job invocation installs and starts a Java-based runtime. You can, however, use the SSH plugin if even one box can run the main Hudson instance.
>
> Cron’s scheduling is more precise if things have to happen exactly at certain time intervals. Hudson’s assumption is that your periodic builds aren’t dependent on when they start within a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

If you like things like logs and results of every execution on a webpage hudson is prefectly usable solution. 
But I wouldn't install hudson just for one cron job unless it was needed for other related tasks anyway.